# Keep the characters before and after a specific character

Tags: text-processing

I want to keep the characters before and after a specific character (_ in this case). I tried cut and sed, but than I remove either the part before the character or after the character.

My output is like this

```
7_38    98.97
7_37    98.59
7_36    98.79
7_35    98.93
7_34    98.57
7_33    99.70
7_32    99.13
```

And I want to delete the number after '_'  and keep the second column to an output like this

```
7   98.97
7   98.59
7   98.79
7   98.93
7   98.57
7   99.70
7   99.13
```

Comment: It would be nice to provide your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to delete `_` and every non-blank character after it, so:

```
sed 's/_[^[:blank:]]*//' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using awk?  This should get you where you want to go:

`awk '/_/ {gsub("_.*","",$1); print}' < input.txt`

Answer (score 0):

With awk ***sub*** function:

```
awk '{ sub("_.*","",$1) }1' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
7   98.97
7   98.59
7   98.79
7   98.93
7   98.57
7   99.70
7   99.13
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use several characters as field separators (space and underscore) and only print fields 1 and 3:

```
awk -F'_| +' '{print($1,$3)}' file
```